# Android - Cannot resolve symbol "devbrackets"

Tags: android, android-studio, libraries, exoplayer

I just installed a new SSD and reimported all my projects on a fresh copy of Android Studio Arctic Fox, and on one of my projects, I am having an issue with this custom view:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.VideoView;

public class PlaybackView extends VideoView {

    public PlaybackView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PlaybackView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public PlaybackView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public PlaybackView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaybackEnded() {
        pause();
    }
}
```

For some reason, Android Studio is giving the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'devbrackets'".  I have the exomedia library imported in Gradle, as well as jcenter() (apparently they have not yet migrated over to mavenCentral).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had to import it in Gradle this way for Android Studio to see it:

```
implementation group: 'com.devbrackets.android', name: 'exomedia', version: '4.3.0'
```

Version 5.0.0 wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this error because android studio chipmunk deleted `jcenter()` as "deprecated". So I just returned `jcenter()`, because **Pink Jazz** right - *devbrackets* have not yet migrated over to mavenCentral for now.